# Generar columnas en un bucle en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando generar varias columnas dadas por el usuario, para mostrar más filas de un script, en este caso, generar aleatoriamente columnas de quinielas. Este es mi código hasta ahora:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo "<center><h2><u>Quiniela</u></h2>
      <form action='ejercicio6.php' method='post'>
      Nº de Columnas: <input type='text' name='x' value=''><br>
      <br><input type='submit' value='Mostrar'></form>";
$x=$_POST['x'];
echo "Columna: ";
$z=0;
while ($z<$x) {
  $posibilidades = array('1','2','X');
  $resultado= array_rand($posibilidades, 1);
  $resultadoclave=$posibilidades[$resultado];
  echo "$resultadoclave ";
  $z++;
}
?>
```

Aun así que indico que el bucle no debe parar hasta que z sea igual que el número x indicado por el usuario, no me generan mas columnas, he intentado con for dentro de for, pero pasaba lo mismo, y no sé que puede estar fallando. Por qué puede estar sucediendo esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la quiniela tiene 15 partidos o resultados, entonces lo que estas haciendo son el número de columnas, no completando los 15 partidos, puedes plantear otro while con el número de columnas y un while con los 15 resultados, indico 10 columnas, tu las columnas las recoges con la variable x del POST.

```
$partidos = 15;
$cols = 10;
$c = 0;

while ($c < $cols)
{
    
    $p=0;
    while ($p <$partidos) 
    {
        $posibilidades = array('1','2','X');
        $resultado= array_rand($posibilidades, 1);
        $resultadoclave=$posibilidades[$resultado];
        echo $resultadoclave . " ";
        $p++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $c++;
}
```